How to get info from image before uploading it to DB using Django?

I have a view that uploads image to database.

I need to get face_encoding before uploading it to database.


Any ideas how to do that?
This is my view:
def index(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = ImageForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse(type(ImageForm))
        else:
            return HttpResponse("error")

    context={'form':ImageForm()}
    template=loader.get_template("core/index.html")
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))

I want to use face_recognition library.

If you intend to encode a face using face_recognition, then you should update your view function
 import face_recognition

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Get uploaded image file
            image_file = request.FILES['image_field_name']

            # Read the image file
            uploaded_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(image_file)

            # Get face encodings
            face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(uploaded_image)

            if len(face_encodings) > 0:
                # Assuming you want to save only the first face encoding
                first_face_encoding = face_encodings[0]

                # Additional processing if needed

                # Save the image to the database along with the face encoding
                instance = form.save(commit=False)
                instance.face_encoding = first_face_encoding.tostring()  # Convert to string for saving in the database
                instance.save()

                return HttpResponse("Image uploaded successfully with face encoding.")
            else:
                return HttpResponse("No face found in the uploaded image.")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid form data.")

    context = {'form': ImageForm()}
    template = loader.get_template("core/index.html")
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

